# Outlook 365 - Is it possible to set to-do list to display only on Outlook Today?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I've been trying to update my Outlook views to show the to-do list on the Outlook Today screen. Unfortunately when I enable it, it is visible on all mail folders when I am hoping to set it up on just the Today screen only. I played with view settings, but it doesn't appear to be something I can modify there. I'm hoping I don't need to resort to VB programming, but am willing if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "visible on all mail folders" here? Did you perform any other specific operations? When creating a new “today” Outlook task, it should automatically be displayed in Outlook Today screen like below:[image]

If necessary, we could change our Outlook today settings Via the “Custom Outlook Today” option in the upper right corner.

Comment: To clarify. Outlook Today only allows you to add or edit Tasks, but does not allow you to add your to-do list items. What I want to make viewable is my to-do list. Which as far as I can find is only viewable from the task menu on the folder pane or if I add the To-Do Bar on the view ribbon. If I add the bar, it remains on screen regardless of where I am in the mail folder. I want that bar to remain **only** while on Outlook Today. Sorry for any confusion on the question!

Comment: Well, I got you. However, it seems impossible to make it only show in Outlook Today. It is a global setting.